# How to size timestamp to millisecond in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a dataframe that has a list of columns; one of the columns is a key_time that has different length. I need to keep all key_time length to millisecond in the second part like:

Original key_time column:

```
  +--------------------+----------------------+
  |account_id          |key_time.             |
  +--------------------+----------------------+
  |9999999.            |2018-07-01 12:32:0424 |
  +--------------------+----------------------+
```

This is what I want:

```
  +--------------------+------------------------+
  |account_id          |key_time.               |
  +--------------------+------------------------+
  |9999999.            |2018-07-01 12:32:042400 |
  +--------------------+----------------------==+
```

and if the second part pass 6 digits then I need to cut it to 6:

```
  +--------------------+------------------------+
  |account_id          |key_time.               |
  +--------------------+------------------------+
  |9999999.            |2018-07-01 12:32:123456 |
  +--------------------+----------------------==+
```

Can I do `df = df.withColumn("key_time", logic (here))`? I am new to Scala, not sure where to begin from here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the type of the key_time column timestamp? Or string?

Comment: @Misha, rather than `6`, shouldn't it be padded or trimmed to `5` digits (i.e. 2 for secs + 3 for millis) if you want the precision down to milliseconds?

Comment: oh yeah, I missed up the digits, that is right, it is 5 digits @LeoC

Comment: @Shaido, it is type of timestamp, I thought that I might need to convert it to string and then do a substring? but then I still have to pad 0 if it is not millisecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to first convert `key_time` to a valid timestamp format via `regexp_extract` then use `date_format` to shape it to the wanted format:

```
val df = Seq(
  (101, "2018-07-01 12:32:0424"),
  (102, "2018-07-01 12:32:123456")
).toDF("account_id ", "key_time")

val pattern = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(.*)"

df.
  withColumn("key_time_1", regexp_extract($"key_time", pattern, 1)).
  withColumn("key_time_2", regexp_extract($"key_time", pattern, 2)).
  withColumn("key_timestamp", concat($"key_time_1", lit("."), $"key_time_2")).
  withColumn("key_time", date_format($"key_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssSSS")).
  select("account_id ", "key_timestamp", "key_time").
  show(false)

// +-----------+------------------------+----------------------+
// |account_id |key_timestamp           |key_time              |
// +-----------+------------------------+----------------------+
// |101        |2018-07-01 12:32:04.24  |2018-07-01 12:32:04240|
// |102        |2018-07-01 12:32:12.3456|2018-07-01 12:32:12345|
// +-----------+------------------------+----------------------+
```